# How do I use the database from cloud with sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying for a while to figure out how to use my cloud postgres data with sequelize.. All I find in tutorials is how to create models locally... I need to access my cloud table and query it. If I use the 'sequelize' object as is, I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
'

```html
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.POSTGRES_URL, {operatorsAliases: false,  logging: false});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Postgres connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the postgres database:', err);
    });

sequelize.findAll().then(users => {
    console.log(users)
});
```

I need to access data from my 'book' table inside the 'shelf' database let's say.

Comment: did you hosted in aws or digital ocean? did you ssh into it?

Comment: You're calling .findAll() on the connection, not one of your models? Also, do you see the connection successful or connection failed errors before you get the TypeError message? You're executing your query immediately after starting the (async) authentication, but the authentication probably hasn't finished by that point.

Comment: You sequelize Object is the database connexion... You have to define the models in your code in order to query in your database... It shouldn't be `sequelize.findAll` but   
 `ỲourMode.findAll()`